# How do I reshape this Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have the first dataframe in Pandas, which I'm trying to reshape to the second dataframe for supervised machine learning purposes. `[foo,bar]` represents a datapoint; each `id` has a definite label `[dog,cat]` and multiple datapoints. The final dataframe includes up to 3 datapoints in the order that they're initially given, using either truncation or zero-padding to achieve this goal.

```py
   foo  bar  dog  cat   id
0  1.1  1.6    0    1   12
1  2.3  2.4    0    1   12
2  4.5  4.2    0    1   12
3  2.3  1.2    0    1   12
4  4.2  3.8    1    0  535
5  1.6  4.1    1    0  535
...
```

```py
 id  foo1  bar1  foo2  bar2  foo3  bar3  dog  cat
 12   1.1   1.6   2.3   2.4   4.5   4.2    0    1
535   4.2   3.8   1.6   4.1     0     0    1    0
...
```

I've tried calling [`pd.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`pd.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), and [`pd.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), but I haven't gotten anywhere. I also haven't been able to find what I'm trying to do on the [Pandas reshaping docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html).

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"How should I design this system?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Also, images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.  Most especially, since you haven't specified how you intend to *use* the data frame, and design would be pure speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot_table` + `cumcount`:

```
df2 = (df.pivot_table(index='id', columns=df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1), 
                      aggfunc='first', fill_value=0)
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df2 = (df2.set_axis([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in df2.columns], 
                    axis=1)
          .reset_index())
print(df2)
```

Or:

```
df2 = (df.assign(groups_id=df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1))
         .set_index(['id', 'groups_id'])
         .unstack(fill_value=0).sort_index(level=1, axis=1))
df2 = (df2.set_axis([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in df2.columns], 
                    axis=1)
          .reset_index())
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
    id  bar1  cat1  dog1  foo1  bar2  cat2  dog2  foo2  bar3  cat3  dog3  \
0   12   1.6     1     0   1.1   2.4     1     0   2.3   4.2     1     0   
1  535   3.8     0     1   4.2   4.1     0     1   1.6   0.0     0     0   

   foo3  bar4  cat4  dog4  foo4  
0   4.5   1.2     1     0   2.3  
1   0.0   0.0     0     0   0.0
```